# Jquery UI Draggable List Item onto Box

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I have a list of items that I want to use the left hand side of the page and these items can be dragged into boxes on the other side. I want the items to be draggable to boxes or be removed.  I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karen_quad/a8wzj14d/) which allows the items to be dragged to the boxes but it is not quite how I want it to work. My issues are as follows:

1. It reorders the boxes and puts them into the left column when the boxes grow.  I want the left hand side to only contain the draggable items.
2. It flickers and doesn't always drag to the location of the cursor.  I am using chrome on a mac.
3. I also want to be able to remove items from boxes.

html:

```js
$(".sortable").sortable({
    revert: true
});
$(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "false",
    placeholder: " droppable-placeholder"
});
$("ul, li").disableSelection();
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.7em;
    float: left;

}

li {
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.draggable-column {
  height:100%;
}

.droppable-item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.sortable {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 2em;

}

.droppable-placeholder {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 draggable-column">
        <ul class="">
            <li class="draggable ">1 Drag me onto item</li>
            <li class="draggable ">2 Drag me onto item</li>
            <li class="draggable ">3 Drag me onto item</li>
            <li class="draggable ">4 Drag me onto item</li>
            <li class="draggable ">5 Drag me onto item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8 droppable-column">

        <div class="col-xs-3 droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 1
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable droppable-placeholder">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 2
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable droppable-placeholder">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 3
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable droppable-placeholder">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 4
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable droppable-placeholder">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 5
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable droppable-placeholder">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 6
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable droppable-placeholder">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: .row {
  display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
}

.col {
  flex: 1; /* additionally, equal width */ 
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
} add this css for your 1st point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked out how to do this but its not particularly clean:

```js
$(".sortable").sortable({
    revert: true,
    connectWith: ".draggable"
   
});

$(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "true",
    placeholder: ".droppable-placeholder",
    
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("--start of stop");
        var listContainer = $(ui.helper[0].parentElement);
        var newListId = listContainer.attr("id");
        var draggableId = $(this).attr("id");
        var cloneId = newListId + "-" + draggableId;
        console.log("new list id: " + newListId);
        console.log("draggableId: " + draggableId);
        console.log("cloneId: " + cloneId);
        var itemExists = false;
        $("#"+ newListId).find('li').each(function() {
            var sortableItemId = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log("sortable item id " + sortableItemId);
            if (sortableItemId != undefined && sortableItemId == cloneId) {
             console.log("***  sortable item already exists");
             itemExists = true;
            } 
        });
        if (itemExists) {
         $("#" + cloneId).remove();
        }
        $(ui.helper[0]).attr("id", cloneId);
        
        console.log("--end of stop");

    },

});


$("ul, li").disableSelection();
$(".draggable-column, .droppable-column").on("click", ".close-list-item", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.7em;
    float: left;
}

li {
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.draggable-column {
    height: 100%;
}

.droppable-item {
    padding: 0.5em;
    float: left;
    align-content: space-between;
}

.droppable-item > h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.sortable {
    width: 230px;
    height: 10em;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.droppable-placeholder {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    /* equal height of the children*/
}

.col {
    flex: 1;
    /* additionally, equal width */
    padding: 1em;
    border: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 draggable-column">
        <ul class="" id="draggable-column-list">
            <li class="draggable " id="item1">1 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="draggable " id="item2">2 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="draggable " id="item3">3 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="draggable " id="item4">4 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="draggable " id="item5">5 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8 droppable-column">

        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 1
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item1">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3 class="">
              Item 2
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item2">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 3
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item3">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 4
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item4">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 5
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item5">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 6
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item6">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```